# The tags [radio] and [radio-communications] should be synonymized or clarified

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Currently, we have [[radio]](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/tags/radio/info) and [[radio-communications]](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/tags/radio-communications/info). The radio tag has a much shorter tag info, and it seems to be basically the same as radio communications. There are 11 questions tagged radio and 62 tagged radio communications. We should either retag questions from radio to radio-communications, synonymize them, or clarify how they are different.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea!

Answer (score 5):

To me they are different and the `radio` tag info should be modified/updated.

Looking at the questions using the tags it seems that also for the community the two tags are not synonyms:

- [radio](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/radio) is mostly used for [equipment related questions](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/radio) (e.g., [antennas](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/12932/), [receivers](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/8939/), [radio systems at large](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/11196/))
- [radio-communications](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/radio-communications) is instead clearly focused to the communication aspect

Comment: That seems to make sense, I would change [tag:radio] to [tag:radio-equipment] and leave [tag:radio-communications] as it is. There may still be some overlap, but I think that's normal.

Comment: Do we need a tag for radio-communications at all, or would a more generic tag like "pilot-communication" or "aircraft-communication" be better? These days various forms of communication other than radio is becoming more and more common (datalink, satellite, etc.)

Comment: @Lnafziger technically they all use radio waves :P

Comment: Technically yes, but in common (and aviation) usage of the terms, no.  :)